# setup:staitic-content:deploy doesn't update JS in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, static-content-deploy

I'm running Magento 2 in production mode.

I made some changes in my module JS files.

I try to make the JS change reflecting on the live site, by using following command.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US en_GB ar_SA
```

I can't see the JS files are updated in pub/static folder.

I have flushed cache php bin/magento cache:flush before and after static-content deploy.

Thanks for your support in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this extension

https://github.com/DominicWatts/ClearStatic

So clear static content first then compile theme.

Might need to do a hard refresh on js in the browser.

Comment: I am unable to install extension

Comment: What is the reason?

Comment: after clear static content. static content files are not regenerating...

Comment: Check permissions on pub folder